# I have a big problem with "Local variable 'guild' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, discord, bots

few months ago I made my own Discord bot. It was all fun and games until I decided to move my bot to my mate's server. So I had to change DISCORD_GUILD in .env file. I did it, however, in shell I only got "Local variable 'guild' referenced before assignment". Please, help me, it's getting hopeless. I spent about 2 weeks on this bot's code...

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Y42.png)

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpCJ4.png)

thanks for any answer!

Edit: after some changes, it says 'unindent does not match any outer indentation level' . I don't get it.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
      print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
      )
```

Edit2: I will just post whole code (without .env ofc)
Here it is:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  for guild in client.guild:
    if guild.name == GUILD:
      break
    print(f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\m')
    print(f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')
```

Comment: The `print` is not under the `for`. You need to indent the `print`.

Comment: You'll get that error if `client.guilds` is empty.

Comment: Wrong indentation. Indent print under the for loop.

Comment: Please don't post code as image, insert it as text.

Comment: @kol still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Barmar what should I do about it?

Comment: @maij sorry, I'm new here, I didn't know how to post it

Comment: The `print()` line needs to be at the same indentation as `if`

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I've corrected it already, but now there is a problem with 'Client' has no atribute 'guild'. Every time I make some corrects, new problem appears :(

Comment: Is it `client.guild` or `client.guilds`?  You've used both, and spelling matters.